# javascript does not submit data to handler if using <a>

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to use following script to submit some data to c# handler when user click on a link

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function myfunc(clicked_id) {
 var params = "{'orderid':'" + clicked_id + "'}";
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", "post");
  form.setAttribute("action", "Handler.ashx");
  // for (var key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "orderid");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
       alert(form.outerHTML.toString());
    }
    //   }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
   form.submit();
    //document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

the following  works fine, but the link does not work for some reason.

```
 <label id="test" ><a href="" onclick="myfunc(this.id)" id="11677113">test</a> </label>
 <input type="button" onclick="myfunc(this.id)" id="11677110" value="test" />
```

basically, i want to invoke a method to cancel an order through javascript(tried using ajax, didnt work either)
Can anyone please help? 
Im using the template website from VS2012 in Razor v2

Comment: You may try to add `return false` to the `a` link after calling `myfunc()` or the link will be fired (and reload the page) before the code has a chance to contact the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An anchor tag has to have a `href` value to be a link, otherwise it becomes a bookmark instead.

Put something in the `href` attribute, and add `return` in the `onclick` so that you can stop the standard action:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return myfunc(this.id)" id="11677113">test</a>
```

To stop the standard action, return `false` from the `myfunc` function.

Answer (score 1):

Stick this `myfunc(this.id)` into the `href` attribute like so:

```
<a href="javascript:myfunc(this.id)" id="11677113">test</a>
```

Currently the empty `href` attribute is canceling the `onclick` as clicking on it makes the page reload.

Comment: this does not seem to fire js

Comment: As the code is not run by an event, `this` doesn't refer to the element.

Answer (score 1):

`href=""` most likely refers to the current URL, so the page is actually unloading.  You could use `href="#"` or bind an event handler using JavaScript and prevent the default behavior:

```
//so so
onclick="myfunc(this.id); return false;"
//best
document.getElementById('11677113').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    myfunc(this.id);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```